# How to display size "human-readable" in lsof | grep /var*

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, terminal, lsof

I am currently trying to see , all the files which are using /var mount.

With `lsof | grep /var*` when Its displaying size in bytes. How can I display file size in MB.

Thank you.

Comment: Side note: you might want to try using `lsof +d /var` instead of `grep`ping.

Answer (score 28):

Starting with GNU Coreutils version 8.21 (released on Dec-2013), there is a new standard program called `numfmt` (=number format).
It will do exactly what you want.

Example:

```
lsof | grep /var*  | numfmt --field=8 --to=iec | head
```

The parameter `--to` accepts `iec` (where 1K=1024B) or `si` (where 1K=1000). There are few additional options, more information here:
http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/numfmt .

(disclaimer: I wrote the initial implementation of `numfmt`).

Comment: This is amazing! Can't wait until every server has this (no RHEL6)!!

Comment: `--field=7` is what you want for `lsof`, which is the SIZE of file that the OP was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
| awk '{$7=$7/1048576 "MB"; print}'
```

or shorter:

```
| awk '{$7=$7/1048576 "MB"}1'
```

Comment: This sounds interesting.. seems minimized. +1\

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk to convert bytes to MB.

Something like this should show size in MB.

```
lsof | grep /var* | awk '{for(i=1;i<=6;i++){printf "%s ", $i}; print $7/1048576 "MB" " "$8" "$9 }'
```

It will print all fields up to 7th field, which is then divided with 1048576 to get the size in MB, and then is shows remaining two fields.

Comment: I have this idea , But I am thinking something internally from lsof and manpage no such information. Thank you for your attention and time on this issue. +1